# rswag rails gem, does not recognize my pattern for create swagger.yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5, rspec-rails, rswag

```
 example : 
rake rswag:specs:swaggerize PATTERN="spec/controllers/api/v1/admin/\*"

or: 

rake rswag:specs:swaggerize pattern="spec/controllers/api/v1/admin/authentications_controller_spec.rb"

or : 
rake rswag:specs:swaggerize pattern="spec/controllers/api/v1/\**/\*_spec.rb"
```

by considering the above code, the swagger.YAML file generates empty. so how I must use a pattern?

Comment: do you mean what is described here :
https://github.com/rswag/rswag#input-location-for-rspec-tests
? if so, I am asking the same thing cause it seems that this way ins not working, can you confirm that giving PATTERN like this actually works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should use the `master` branch.

```
gem 'rswag', github: 'rswag/rswag', branch: 'master'
```

then

```
rake rswag:specs:swaggerize PATTERN="spec/controllers/**/*_spec.rb"
```

Hope it works as expected ;)